# Should a Thread and a Post be the same model in a web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, model

I'm creating a new forum web app in rails.

Should a Thread and a Post be the same model or a different model?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each option ?
when should it be the same model and when should i choose to separate the two ?

Thread - has a title and a body. has many posts.

Post - has only body, the posts are arranged as a tree (acts_as_tree)

Edit : they both can be voted on, only a thread can be tagged

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Posts and Threads both have a body isn't enough to make them the same model. They are different enough to be different models, especially when you have a clear one-to-many relationship.

You probably want to read about [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), particularly [has_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) (which includes has_many :through), [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association-reference), and [belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association).

In this case, make Thread's has_many refer to Post. My guess is that a Post can only be in one thread. If so, then you want Post's belongs_to to refer to Thread.

Comment: They could however be the same model (Post having a parent attribute). It's pretty much up to the specific use case...

Comment: What are the examples of use cases where Post should be the only model ?

Answer (score 0):

I would presume you can go down both the Threads (1) to Posts (N) path **AND** the Posts-only model.

If the exact same data is being stored for both, I don't see why you *CAN'T* model it all as one table.  Here's how:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
  post_id serial,
  post_thread_id int,
  post_number int,
  post_title character varying,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY(post_id)
);
INSERT INTO posts(post_thread_id, post_number, post_title) VALUES (1, 1, 'Welcome to my thread!');
INSERT INTO posts(post_thread_id, post_number, post_title) VALUES (1, 2, 'The first response!');
INSERT INTO posts(post_thread_id, post_number, post_title) VALUES (1, 3, 'The second response!');
```

Obviously, there's some undesirable bits and pieces to such a design, but...it can be done.